# How to show line numbers in all files in AppCode?

Tags: objective-c, appcode

I can select "show line numbers" for every files, but I want AppCode editor to show line numbers for each files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance | Show Line Numbers